Raise exception in .map_elements()
Update: This was fixed by pull/20417 in Polars 1.18.0

I'm using .map_elements to apply a complex Python function to every element of a polars series. This is a toy example:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})

def sum_cols(row):
    return row["A"] + row["B"]

df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all())
    .map_elements(sum_cols, return_dtype=pl.Int32).alias("summed")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ summed │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i32    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 5      │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 7      │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9      │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘

However, when my function raises an exception, Polars silently uses Nulls as the output of the computation:
def sum_cols(row):
    raise Exception
    return row["A"] + row["B"]

df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all())
    .map_elements(sum_cols, return_dtype=pl.Int32).alias("summed")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ summed │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i32    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ null   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ null   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ null   │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘

How can I make the Polars command fail when my function raises an exception?

It's a bug. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/19315

@jqurious That means someone else has reported it as a bug. It's still in needs-triage state, so the developers haven't reviewed it and acknowledged that it's a bug rather than by design.

@Barmar Yes, but it is a bug. Why would silently swallowing exceptions be by design? .map_batches() propagates the exception as expected.

@jqurious It's not something that happens by accident, someone had to put an explicit try/except to do it. So they presumably thought it was a good idea at the time.

@Barmar It's happening at the Rust level, not because of a try/except. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/71a8b0543362aadb771c2a446ac93756ea36a124/crates/polars-python/src/map/series.rs#L236-L237

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Polars.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/19315
https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14821

As a workaround, you could use .map_batches() to pass the whole "column" instead:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})

def sum_cols(col):
    raise Exception
    return pl.Series(row["A"] + row["B"] for row in col)

df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all()).map_batches(sum_cols)
)

Which propagates exceptions as one would expect.
# ComputeError: Exception: 


Adding an answer based on @jqurious observation that this is an issue reported here.
The issue claims that map_elements swallows exceptions only when the return_dtype= argument is set.
Upon testing, that seems to be the case:
def sum_cols(row):
    raise Exception

df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all())
    .map_elements(sum_cols).alias("summed")
)


ComputeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ComputeError: Exception: 

Apart from not being able to specify the return type, a down side is that when calling map_elements without this argument, we get a warning, but I feel it's a problem I can live with before the issue is resolved in Polars
def sum_cols(row):
    return row["A"] + row["B"]

df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all())
    .map_elements(sum_cols).alias("summed")
)


/var/folders/2x/flqt0w710b1b2hx21x2kql_r0000gn/T/ipykernel_14024/3751275743.py:4: MapWithoutReturnDtypeWarning: Calling `map_elements` without specifying `return_dtype` can lead to unpredictable results. Specify `return_dtype` to silence this warning.

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ summed │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 5      │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 7      │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9      │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘

